# Explicit projection from a projective module to an algebra

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a finite dimensional $k$-algebra.

The map $n \mapsto f_n$ where $f_n:A \to N$ is given by $f_n(a)=n a$ defines an embedding of $N$ into a $(A^e,1\otimes A^{op})$-injective module, $N \to Hom_k(A,N)$, for all left $A^e$-module $N$.
Where $A^e=A \otimes_k A^{op}$ is the enveloping algebra.

I have been trying to construct in a similar way, an explicit $(A^e,1\otimes A^{op})$-projective module $P(N)$, together with a surjection $P(N) \to A$ for every left $A^e$-module $N$, but have not been succesfull.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the second paragraph. If $a\in A$ then $f_a$ is a map $A\to A$, not $A\to M$. Maybe you want to define a map $M\to\text{Hom}_k(A,M)$ rather than  $A\to\text{Hom}_k(A,M)$?

Comment: Also, for an $A^e$-module $N$, $\text{Hom}_k(A,N)$ does not in general have the structure of an injective $A^e$-module. For example, let $A=k[x]/(x^2)$. Then there is a $1$-dimensional simple $A^e$-module $N$, for which $\text{Hom}_k(A,N)$ is $2$-dimensional. But the unique indecomposable injective $A^e$-module is $4$-dimensional.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes, I had some typos.

Comment: It was $(A^e,1\otimes A^{op})$-injective, not left $A^e$-injective